# Custom Action For Xtify Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, push-notification, xtify

I use Xtify's web service for push notifications.  They have a way to perform custom action on click, but I'm not sure I'm understanding how to do it.  Basically, I want the custom action to allow me to choose which tab to open the app to.  Their link is 
    http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/6.+Other+Implementation+Methods

What all would I need to set up in app to specifiy in push notification which tab to open up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to set a delegate with a method that would be called wherever you want it to be called as specified in the documentation -

```
[[XLappMgr get] setDeveloperCustomActionSelector:@selector(developerCustomActionMethod:)];
```

Then you would need to define a method called developerCustomActionMethod which does the actual switching. You could use the following code to select which tab you need to switch to -

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]; // will select the third tab, as tabs are ranked 0,1,2,3,....
```